# Integrate $\int \frac{\sin^2(x)}{1+\sin^2(x)}dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Got any ideas (what substitution should I use) to evaluate $$\int \frac{\sin^2(x)}{1+\sin^2(x)}dx~?$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Write:
$$\frac {\sin^2 x} {1 + \sin^2 x} = \frac {1 +\sin^2 x - 1} {1 + \sin^2 x} = 1 - \frac 1 {1 + \sin^2 x} = 1 - \frac {\sec^2 x} {\sec^2 x + \tan^2 x}  =  1 - \frac {\sec^2 x} {1 + 2\tan^2 x} $$

Now substitute $u = \tan x$ and the rest is easy.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Weierstrass substitution? (That is, $t=\tan{(x/2)}$) This is a rational function of $\sin$ and $\cos$, so it should in principle work, although I suspect it will be messy.

Comment: How does the differential $dx$ change when one uses Weierstrass substitution?

Comment: $dx = \frac{2 dt}{1+t^2}$. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_substitution for more details on this method. (Thanks to Jules for noticing the error in my previous comment.)